# How Filter Binding Source Connected To linq Query

Tags: linq, filter, bindingsource

i have a sql table "Activity" which includes .ID , .Activ_Code , .Name , .Start , .End

```
Dim BS as BindingSource
Dim DGView as Datagridview


BS.Datasource=(From x in Dbase.Activity select x)
BS.Filter="Activ_Code=3"
DGView.datasource=BS
```

this shows all fields from "Activity" Table. 
i changed Filter property to  "Activ_Code='3'" and "Activ_Code LIKE 3" but none of them works.

Comment: what about:
BS.Datasource=(From x in Dbase.Activity where x.Activ_Code==3 select x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Only underlying lists that implement the IBindingListView interface support filtering.

The datasource is just an `IEnumerable`. You have to filter in the LINQ query itself. For instance:

```
Dim mainList = (From x in Dbase.Activity select x).ToList
BS.Datasource=(From x in mainList.Where(...) select x)
```

and put your filter at the dots. Each time you set the data source to a new filtered list, the objects *in* the list won't be affected because they are not re-fetched from the database.

Comment: i cant do it because by changing query each time, will discard changes in underlying list. i need to save changes at last.

Comment: Then keep the full list in memory and show a filtered list, coming form the in-memory list, in the view.

Comment: thanks that was really helpful. but now i have another problem.
Removing records from BS do not Affect Mainlist.
i mean buy calling BS.Removecurrent() and then BS.EndEdit() , Mainlist remains The Same as before Removing.